# JSON.parse produces a SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, json

Inputting this:

```
JSON.parse("{list : []}");
```

produces this in the console:

```
VM9793:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at <anonymous>:1:6
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a question here, or just a statement that a bad JSON string properly throws an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) requires object keys to be stings, so it needs to be:

```
JSON.parse('{"list" : []}');
```

Comment: My trouble was when I tried JSON.parse("{'list' : []}"); (double quotes on the outside), it didn't work, so I assumed something else was wrong. Is there a reason why the double quote needs to be inside?

Comment: @jKo That's because in JSON strings are required to be in double quotes, it doesn't take single quotes.